# Multiple web paged as mobi

Tags: kindle

I have Kindle 5 and I use Amazon's "Send to Kindle" pluggin. It sends one article from browser into the kindle. I would like to send multiple articles as one mobi file.

```
Example:
1. Add article A as Kindle content (stores article A into the memory)
2. Add article B as Kindle content (stores article B into the memory)
3. Add article C as Kindle content (stores article C into the memory)
...
4. Send all articles into the Kindle (takes all 3 articles and sends them into the Kindle as one file)
```

Is there some pluggin or feature which will do this functionality?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend either [Instapaper.com](http://Instapaper.com) or [Readability.com](http://www.Readability.com) for this use case.

These are web (and app, e.g. iOS, Android) based solutions, both have browser bookmarklets to save an article to your personal reading list, and both are capable of sending batches of articles.